# Do answers, given during grace period, count for a bounty?

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

Just curious..

A while ago, I commented on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/523937/shift-any-key-combination-closes-search-dialog-in-gedit-on-14-04#comment723729_523937), to see if I could find information to give an answer. Just after the bounty period, but within the grace period, the poster commented that although I didn't actually answer the question, my comments had lead him to the solution.

He asked me to summarize my comments, to be able to award the bounty which I was happy to do of course. He was unable to award the bounty however, which made me curious: do answers during the grace period count for a bounty, or is the grace period only to evaluate the late answers?

[This link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) suggests they do count, [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134963) says it is practice on SE, but [here](https://askubuntu.com/help/bounty) is no clear description on this concerning AU. Not that it is about a brilliant answer here, but I'd really like to know if what happened is correct or not.

Comment: The one with the examples is two years old. It's possible they fixed the behaviour since then.

Comment: User only can awarded the Bounty, 24 hours or more after that you answered the question.

Comment: @KasiyA where can I find that? not here: http://askubuntu.com/help/bounty

Comment: That's not mentioned any where. It just happened for me 7 days ago when I open a bounty ;) for [this my question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/527054/how-to-customize-terminals-commands-output) and @c0rp's answer worked for me then I tried to award the bounty for him/her but an error under bounty said that "you can award the bounty after 24 hours later..." I think If I don't forget that.

Comment: @KasiyA I think rules about that (any) should be written somewhere to be valid.

Comment: uh I take a mistake. I mean, that is nowhere mentioned/written.

Comment: @KasiyA but that is what I mean, for a rule to be valid, you should be able to take notice before you are confronted with it :)

Comment: unfortunately...